# How can I create a product with a single variation for a store?

Tags: 8, commerce

I am having trouble with creating products for a commerce project with multiple sellers (each with their own store).  The products these sellers are selling is a baseball card.

When a user adds a new product to sell, in the form submission I create the form as:

```
// create price...
$price = new Price($vals['price']['number'], $vals['price']['currency_code']);

// init variation
$variation_vals = [
  'type' => 'card_type_baseball',
  'status' => 1,
  'sku' => 'baseball-1',
  'price' => $price,
  'field_card_image' => [$vals['image_fid']]
];
$variant = ProductVariation::create($variation_vals);
$variant->save();

// init product
$product_vals = [
  'uid' => $this->getUID(),
  'title' => $vals['name'],
  'type' => 'card',
  'stores' => [$this->store],
  'variations' => [$variant],
];
$product = Product::create($product_vals);
$product->save();
```

It works, however, when I view the product after creation, I have many copies of image and field values for some reason.

I think I'm missing a concept.

When a user wants to sell their product, and they upload the product image, set the price, and enter the title for that card (through the form I provide via the Form API) I want to create the product that I can display in a view for the front page, or under their store on their store pages (which I can display via Views).

Every card has the same properties: an image, title, and a price. Examples,

1 - Barry Bonds, $20.00 (with img)
2 - Mark McGuire, $15.00 (with img)

Am I missing something in relation to creating products?

Comment: It's looking like it may have been a rendering issue, where I was rendering the variation entity, and within the variation, I was rendering the product, getting what I assume to be a cascading effect.  I'm still unsure, however, that I have the concept down for the multi-selling system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in my example was fine.  In my product variation's display I was rendering the product entity, and in my product entity I was rendering my variant.  If anyone encounters multiple copies of their product rendered, check how the fields are rendered in the display.